# How can I remove repeated characters from strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to clean the 'name' column in this dataframe. It has repeated characters that all follow the same pattern. Check out the image below for reference.

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: `df["name"]=df["name"].apply(lambda x:x[:len(x)//2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just extract second half of the string for each row like this:

```
df["name"]=df["name"].apply(lambda x:x[:int(len(x)/2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The name field is repeated so just halve the string

```
x='namename'
x[:len(x)//2]
'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

***You should be solving the underlying problem instead of doing this.***

Reguardless, to do this all you need to do is shorten the string by half

```
import math

def half_str(name: str):
    return name[:math.ceil(len(name)/2)]
```

Here are some examples from your database:

```
print(half_str("John SmithJohn Smith")) # "John Smith"
print(half_str("Ty GoodenTyGooden")) # "Ty Gooden"
```